# How to print a list with out printing line numbers?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a list of ggplot objects that I am using the `print()` function to display. When I do this in r markdown it adds `` ## $`item name` ``  where "item name" is the name of the object in the list. It adds this before every ggplot object. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). To get good and helpful answers, it is best to provide a minimal reproducible example. You can make use of `dput` to provide data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unname` function to make the list printed as usual

```
a <- list(`one` = 2 , `two` = 3 , `three` = 4)

print(unname(a))

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 4
```